# Adding a conditional for a colon within a Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse text from a transcript that looks something like this:

> LESTER HOLT (dfjk) (00:01:59): Donald Trump’s path to the presidency
>   might be the most unusual and unorthodox we’ve ever seen.
>
> CHIEF JUSTICE JOHN ROBERTS (00:02:06): Congratulations, Mister
>   President.
>
> (00:02:08) (Crowd cheering and applause)

The items I'm looking for are optional speaker [i.e. 'LESTER HOLT'], followed by optional text within parantheses [i.e. '(vo)'], followed by optional timestamp within parantheses [i.e. '(00:02:03)'], followed by text [i.e. 'Hello, hi.'].
After a timestamp, there may or may not be a colon [':']. See above example, last line, in which there is no colon.

I'm using the following regex:
`([a-zA-Z\s]*?)?\s?(\([\w\s]*?\))?\s?(\(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\))?\s?:(.*)(?:\n\n|$)`

The issue arises on the last line in the example above. The lack of a colon after the timestamp causes the regex to not capture the timestamp.

See https://regex101.com/r/UZAnmW/4 for my implementation of the above regex.

[Here is the desired result, which (with above regex) only happens if there is a colon after timestamp.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbtcW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
([a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s?(\([\w\s]*\))?\s?(\(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\))?\s?:?(.*)(?:\n\n|$)
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/UZAnmW/6

Answer (score 1):

This regex may help, it is far simpler and uses optional named groups to help with readability and accessing the results:

```
(?<speaker>(?:\w+\s?)+)?(?<paren>\(\w+\)\s?)?(?<timestamp>\(.*?\))?:?(?<text>.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/9MDLFU/4/

Also, your regex works with a [couple changes](https://regex101.com/r/vBbZpo/2): (first group must match at least one character, colon is optional, and the last group must also match at least one character):

`([a-zA-Z\s]+)?\s?(\([\w\s]*?\))?\s?(\(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\))?\s?:?(.+)(?:\n\n|$)`